# display flax changes images height

Tags: html, css

```
<div id='wrap'>
<img id='eleph01' src='img/eleph01.gif' alt='elephant'>&nbsp;
<img id='eleph02' src='img/eleph01.gif' alt='elephant'>&nbsp;
<img id='eleph03' src='img/eleph01.gif' alt='elephant'>
</div>
```

css

```
#wrap{
    display:flex;
    justify-content:space-between;  
}
#eleph01{
    width:200px;
}
#eleph02{
    width:150px;
}
#eleph03{
    width:100px;
}
```

Why images are distorted to the same height? I need to keep their aspect ratio and just distribute them horizontally.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7zxvf/)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove the `display:flex` from your css.You can refer to this [link](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox) A flex container expands items to fill available free space, or shrinks them to prevent overflow.You can check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7zxvf/1/)